# Use filter to only show the corresponding data in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When the user clicks on a list item, I want it to render the paragraph content for that list item. When the user clicks on another list item, I then want to erase the previous content and register then new paragraph data for the new list item. Currently, when I click the list items, the info data stays for all and never goes away. Does this make sense? If you go to this website https://brittanychiang.com/ and click the "experience" button in the nav, you can see the functionality I am going for.

Questions :

```
import SingleQuestion from "./SingleQuestion";
import classes from "./Question.module.css";

const questions = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Step 1",
    info: "paragraph 1 text",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Step 2",
    info: "paragraph 2 text",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "Step 3",
    info: "paragraph 3 text",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: "Step 4",
    info: "paragraph 4 text",
  },
];

const Questions = () => {
  return (
    <main>
      <h1 className="infoTitle">We have answers</h1>
      <div className={classes.container}>
        {questions.map((question) => {
          return <SingleQuestion key={question.id} {...question} />;
        })}
      </div>
    </main>
  );
};
export default Questions;
```

SingleQuestion:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import classes from "./Question.module.css";

const SingleQuestion = ({ title, info }) => {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  const showTextHandler = () => {
    setText(info);
  };

  return (
    <section className={classes.elementBin}>
      <ul>
        <li className={classes.hi} onClick={showTextHandler}>
          {title}
        </li>
      </ul>
      <p>{text}</p>
    </section>
  );
};

export default SingleQuestion;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of ways of solving this, I will just show an example that does not differ so much from your current code:

```
const Questions = () => {
  const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState();

  return (
    <main>
      <h1 className="infoTitle">We have answers</h1>
      <div className={classes.container}>
        {questions.map((question) => {
          return (
            <SingleQuestion
              key={question.id}
              isSelected={question.id === selectedId}
              setSelectedId={setSelectedId}
              {...question}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </main>
  );
};

const SingleQuestion = ({ id, title, info, isSelected, setSelectedId }) => {
  return (
    <section className={classes.elementBin}>
      <ul>
        <li className={classes.hi} onClick={() => setSelectedId(id)}>{title}</li>
      </ul>
      {isSelected && <p>{info}</p>}
    </section>
  );
};
```

As you can see, an upper state was created, holding the selected question id.

The setter for that state is passed to the **SingleQuestion** component.

Now that component does not hold an internal state anymore, it just update the selected question id, and shows its info just if is the selected one.